# Count of Occurrences from the transaction DateTime + 1 Hour in SQL

Tags: sql, timestamp, window-functions

I have the Dataset Like

```
Transaction Time      A     B    C      Expected Output
3/17/2020 14:42      India  1   10        2
3/17/2020 15:09      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 15:48      India  1   10        4
3/17/2020 15:59      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 16:13      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 16:36      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 17:02      India  1   10        1
3/17/2020 18:42      India  1   10        5
3/17/2020 18:55      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 19:05      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 19:24      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 19:30      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 20:01      India  1   10        1
3/17/2020 21:24      India  1   10        3
3/17/2020 21:26      India  1   10        0
3/17/2020 21:48      India  1   10        0
```

The Dataset is based on the transaction Datetime with some of the dimensions associated to it.

The first transaction occured on: 3/17/2020 14:42 , I want to know how many such transactions are available between the first transaction date and next 1 hour interval. So In the data we can see the first and second record satisfies this criteria so the last column "Expected Output" as 2 in the first row and 0 in the 2nd row.

again the counter will start from the third records : 3/17/2020 15:48 so for this record we can see there are total of 4 such transactions which falls between and current datetime + 1 hour interval so the 3 row is set as 4 and the row 4,5,6 is set as 0 and so on.

Requesting your help on the same.

Comment: Sorry, but by what logic would the counter be reseted?  What's the real world idea behind that? Your description seems to imply that the expected output is dependent on the min transaction timestamp queried, which sound rather weird. Do we agree that without a reset logic, the expected result in line 2 would be 3 as two consecutive  transaction happen within one hour of transaction 2?

Comment: The main agenda is to show how many such transactions are falling between every one hour starting with the first transaction of the day. So in the example above we can make our that there were one occurrences of 5 transactions, one occurances of 4 and one for 3.

Comment: Ok, after trying for a while, I do see no other solution then  something involving a cursor. What dbms are you on?